# How to give hive query into sperate file for each query?

Tags: unix, hive, scripting, hiveql

I have a .sql file in which there are 100s of hive queries and i want their output in a multiple files, like for 1st query abc.txt file gets created for 2nd query xyz.txt file gets created and so on....for 100 queries 100 output file with their result respectively

Comment: How are the individual sqls separated in the file. Do you have semicolons after each sql?

Comment: I have new line separator after every query

Comment: So does it mean that all your queries occupy a single  line ? Can you show few lines from your query file?

Comment: Select * from table_name1;
Select * from table_name2;

Comment: It is not clear. edit your question and show sample 5-6 lines from your file.

Answer (score 0):

If your main .sql file has semicolon separated sql queries, you could use an `awk` command like this to generate separate hive commands with output files.

```
tr '\n' ' ' < yourqueryfile | awk 'BEGIN {RS=";"} \
{gsub(/(^ +| +$)/, "", $0);printf "hive -e \"%s\" >OUT_"NF".txt\n",$0}'
```

`RS=";"` - sets record separator to ";"

`tr` - to replace newlines between queries to single space.

`gsub` -  to trim leading and trailing spaces.

The command will generate multiple hive command lines like this.

```
hive -e "select 1" >OUT_2.txt
hive -e "select 3 from ( select 4 )" >OUT_7.txt
hive -e "select name from t union  select n from t2" >OUT_9.txt
hive -e "select * from c" >OUT_4.txt
```